# Maclaurin series with radius of convergence $R$, non-negative coefficients and a pole $z=R$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am new here and this is my first post. Also, I am new to complex analysis and I am facing some difficulties to solve the following exercise:

[image]

I have been reading the following solution:

[image]

But I do not understand how they use that $a_k \geq 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
On the other hand, I think that I can apply their argument to the meromorphic function defined by $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$, which has a pole at $z_0=1$ and is analytic at $z_1 = -1$ and has a power series expansion at $z_2 = -1/2$ with radius $R = \frac{3}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon$.

Can anyone help me understand this proof?

Comment: Nonnegativity of $a_n$ is applied for changing the order of infinite sums, as all the terms are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be as follows.

Assumptions imply that the radius of convergence of the MacLaurin series is equal $r.$ Assume there is no pole at $z=r.$ Then the function $f(z)$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $r.$ In particular
$$f(r)=\lim_{x\to r^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to r^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$ As $a_n\ge 0$ and $0<x<r$ the limit is equal
$$f(r)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^n$$ That means the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$ is absolutely summable for $|z|\le r$ (by the M-test) and represents there a **continuous bounded** function, equal $f(z)$ for $|z|<r.$
This implies that $f(z)$ cannot have a pole at  any point $|z|=r,$ which leads to a contradiction.